# Is it best practice to escape create react app and create our own template to get React project ready for production?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and recently joined a team and my first assignment was to set up a react project without using create-react-app because as team lead told me custom template makes easier to put react into production. Then, the question is how about create-react-app helping us with all of the setup for us and if we want to customize the CRA we can use npm run eject. So, why should we create our own template?

Comment: do you consider `server-side-rendering`?

Comment: CRA generates a very simple application which you can customize to no end. The two aren't at all mutually exclusive. You'd have to clarify what "easier to put into production" means for us to respond to that.

Comment: @PrateekThapa, no, I mean, when exactly should we prefer custom template instead of create-react-app? Because I also want to dockerize my react app

Comment: @isherwood, ok I mean in a nutshell, when should we prefer  custom template instead of create-react-app? Also, in real world projects we initially develop react project locally but when we deploy something breaks. That is I meant by "easier to put into production". I just want to understand why should we prefer custom template? is it to help for easier dockerization of react project? or?

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, it's pretty hard [to setup a React application](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) without a template.

You can check [Creating a Toolchain from Scratch](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#creating-a-toolchain-from-scratch) at React docs which refers to [this guide](https://blog.usejournal.com/creating-a-react-app-from-scratch-f3c693b84658?gi=7175e513167c).

Your own template should configure **package manager**, **bundler** and **compiler**, it's not so trivial. Best suggestion would be extending CRA by cloning the repo or running `yarn eject` and continue from there.

Comment: I just want to then dockerize react app therefore can it be considered better to use custom template in lieu of CRA for easier dockerization? or?

Comment: the team lead literally told me that we need custom template because we then transfer react project into production and thus it would allow us to customize the template. The question is for what reason can we possibly customize the template?

Comment: You can dockerize anything, it has nothing to with what template you use. Try reading the docs I shared, it tells you about CRA alternatives, there are plenty projects in production which uses CRA and dockers its nothing special.